# How to use Flink's KafkaSource with Scala in 2022

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I've checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419408/how-to-use-flinks-kafkasource-in-scala) similar but 7 year old question but it does not apply to newer Flink versions.

I'm trying to get a simple Flink Kafka job running and have tried various versions getting different compile errors for each. I'm using sbt to manage my dependencies:

```
val flinkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion
)
```

**Versions tried:**
scala 2.11.12 and 2.12.15
flink 1.14.6

**The code I'm trying to compile (relevant bits):**

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource

...

  val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaSource.builder[String]
    .setBootstrapservers("localhost:9092")
    .setGroupId("flink")
    .setTopics("test")
    .build()

  val text = env.fromSource(kafkaConsumer)
```

I did not find an official example that this is indeed how one is supposed to use the `KafkaSource` but I found this setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72208849/20173985) and [here](https://github.com/springMoon/flink-rookie/blob/979010816d45907c56df507324ad47e7fb75b804/src/main/scala/com/venn/stream/api/dayWindow/DynamicWindow.scala#L42-L53). To my still very new Java eyes this looks aligned with the [API docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/api/java/). But yeah can't get it to work with either Scala version:

```
[error] somepathwithmyfile: type builder is not a member of object org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource
[error]     val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaSource.builder[String]
[error]                                         ^
[error] somepathwithmyfile: value fromSource is not a member of org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment
[error]     val text = env.fromSource(kafkaConsumer)
[error]                    ^
[error] two errors found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, drop the `new`:

```scala
 val kafkaConsumer = KafkaSource.builder[String]
   ...
```

For the second problem, `fromSource` requires three arguments:

```scala
  /** Create a DataStream using a [[Source]]. */
  @Experimental
  def fromSource[T: TypeInformation](
      source: Source[T, _ <: SourceSplit, _],
      watermarkStrategy: WatermarkStrategy[T],
      sourceName: String): DataStream[T] = {

    val typeInfo = implicitly[TypeInformation[T]]
    asScalaStream(javaEnv.fromSource(source, watermarkStrategy, sourceName, typeInfo))
  }
```

Also, note that Flink does not (yet) support scala 2.12.15. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20969. However, Flink 1.15 can be used with newer versions of Scala (including Scala 3), if you exclude Flink's built-in scala API support. See https://flink.apache.org/2022/02/22/scala-free.html for more on this.

Comment: Thank you so much David, please excuse what I now realize was a very stupid question.

Comment: No problem. And see my updated answer re: scala 2.12.15.